# How to mount onedrive to google colaboratory?

Tags: deep-learning, google-drive-api, onedrive, google-colaboratory

I use google colab with google drive in deep-learning training, but although I've 100gb premium account, sometimes it accouring error that `find: ‘/content/drive/My Drive/Deep_Learning/Deep_Fashion_Dataset/.../’: Input/output error
0` sometimes.

So I want to mount my onedrive account to google colab, is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html#drive-timeout explains the likely culprit for the I/O errors you see.

There is no built-in support in colab for onedrive, but maybe https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/07/how-to-mount-onedrive-in-linux-using.html is useful (I haven't tried it).

Answer (score 0):

You can use OneDriveSDK which available for download in the PyPi index.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Microsoft has made this possible. Check the following link:

https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using **rclone**.

Rclone is a command-line program to manage files on cloud storage. It is a feature-rich alternative to cloud vendors' web storage interfaces. Over 40 cloud storage products support including **OneDrive**.

Rclone is single executable (rclone, or rclone.exe on Windows) that you can simply download as a zip archive and extract into a location of your choosing.

[Click here to download the rclone zip folder](https://rclone.org/downloads/)

[Then follow this tutorial on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U6YPgARhRzA)